# Multi test correction and hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I have 9 datasets with one predictor and one target attribute. For each of the dataset, I am testing for a single hypothesis - whether the attributes are associated. I have got the following based on the test-statistic:

- Uncorrected *p*-values: 8 out of 9 p-values are significant ($p\le\alpha$)
- Bonferroni correction (FWER): 3 out of 9 p-values are significant ($p\le\alpha_{corrected}$)
- Benjamini–Hochberg correction (FDR): 6 out of 9 p-values are significant ($p\le\alpha_{B\&H}$)

I could combine 9 datasets but I am testing for each dataset separately because the context of the data in each dataset is important.

**Question:** Based on these findings, should I accept or reject the null hypothesis (the 2 attributes are not correlated?) and what could be the formal reasoning behind that?

The model is expected to produce few FP/FN but we are not sure to which extent. So we can allow a few errors from the model.

Comment: Well, the two attributes are significantly different in 6 out of 9 data sets, is what I would say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in an association between the same predictor & target in all the datasets, you are using your dataset inefficiently by doing independent tests in each of them. Instead, consider using a [mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model) (a.k.a. hierarchical model) with `dataset` as a random effect (random intercept or random intercept + slope).

Essentially, it is a regression that models a single overall effect (for which you can compute a p-value) while allowing that effect to differ between groups (the datasets, in your cases). The differing contexts of the individual datasets is accounted for this way. This approach benefits from *partial pooling* of the datasets, as opposed to complete pooling, in which you merge all the individual datasets into one, undifferentiated large dataset. As a result, you use your data more efficiently and this has the side benefit of avoiding any confusion around corrections for multiple comparisons.